# PySpark passing Dataframe as extra parameter to map

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to parallelize a python list, use a map on that list, and pass a Dataframe to the mapper function also

```
def output_age_split(df):
   ages= [18, 19, 20, 21, 22]
   age_dfs= spark.sparkContext.parallelize(ages).map(lambda x: test(x, df)
# Unsure of type of age_dfs, but should be able to split into the smaller dfs like this somehow
return age_dfs[0], age_dfs[1] ...

def test(age, df):
   return df.where(col("age")==age)
```

This results in a pickling error

```
  raise pickle.PicklingError(msg)
  _pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

How should i parallelize this operation so that i get returned a collection of Dataframes?

EDIT: Sample of df

```
|age|name|salary|
|---|----|------|
|18 |John|40000 |
|22 |Joseph|60000 |
```

Comment: Assuming `df` is a separate dataframe, are you expecting multiple dataframes as output of `output_age_split`? The way I see it, `test` function is going to return a dataframe, and the `df` dataframe would be split into 5 smaller dataframe. Is that what you want? Also, please provide a sample for `df` dataframe.

Comment: @KumarRohit Yes output_age_split should return dataframe for each age , 
What i want is the age_dfs variable in output_age_split to be some kind of collection where i can split it into its 5 smaller dataframes and return them seperately, Edited code for clarity

Comment: Added solution in the answer section. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `ages_dfs` is not a dataframe, it's an `RDD`. Now, when you are applying a `map` with `test` function in it (which returns the `dataframe`), we end up getting into a weird situation where `ages_dfs` is actually an `RDD` of type `PipelinedRDD` which is neither a `dataframe` nor `iterable`.

`TypeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable`

You can try the below workaround, where you just iterate on the list instead and create a collection of `dataframe` and iterate on them at will.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

def output_age_split(df):
  ages = [18, 19, 20, 21, 22]
  result = []
  for age in ages:
    temp_df = test(age, df)
    if(not len(temp_df.head(1)) == 0):
      result.append(temp_df)
  return result 

def test(age, df):
   return df.where(col("age")==age)

# +---+------+------+
# |age|name  |salary|
# +---+------+------+
# |18 |John  |40000 |
# |22 |Joseph|60000 |
# +---+------+------+
df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(
  [
    (18, "John", 40000),
    (22, "Jpseph", 60000)
  ]
).toDF(["age", "name", "salary"])
                                                      
df.show()

result = output_age_split(df)
# Output type is: <class 'list'>

print(f"Output type is: {type(result)}")
for r in result:
  r.show()

# +---+----+------+
# |age|name|salary|
# +---+----+------+
# | 18|John| 40000|
# +---+----+------+

# +---+------+------+
# |age|  name|salary|
# +---+------+------+
# | 22|Jpseph| 60000|
# +---+------+------+
```

I am also attaching screenshot from my workspace for your reference.

Problem: [image]

Solution: [image]

Comment: Hi @KumarRohit , thank you for the the solution, Unfortunately, this is the situation i want to avoid, as this solution does not operate in parallel , it is much to slow due to the size of the dataset. This will filter for each age sequentially, I was hoping to find a solution where this could be done in paralell

Comment: You can `repartition` your dataframe on `age` and do a `foreachPartition`, that will split your data logically and you would still be able to leverage parallel processing capabilities of spark. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartition.html  https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.foreachPartition.html

Comment: Would you have an example of how to use this? forEachPartition does not return anything, I assume the relevant function here would actually be rdd.mapPartitions

I had tried using that as follows:
`df= df.repartition("age")`
`age_dfs = df.rdd.mapPartitions(lambda x: x)`
But the problem is, it returns it as one Rdd instead of split, So it essentially does nothing

Comment: Can you provide me with the specific transformation you want to conduct on these split datasets?

Comment: I simply want to return each partition in a seperate dataframe